# How to Join two tables for list vector plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I trying to combine two tables for a vector plot.

Consider one table

```
data = Table[{x, -y}, {x, -6, 0}, {y, -6, 0}]
```

We can easily apply the function `ListVectorPlot` on this table and it works correctly.

Now to the `data` I want add another data.

```
data2 = Join[%, Table[{x, -y}, {x, 1, 6}, {y, 1, 6}]]
```

Note that there is a "missing region $x\in (0,1) ∧ y\in(0,1)$.
Now If we apply `ListVectorPlot` to `data2` I get the error "data2 is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets". How do I fix this error?

Comment: I am not sure that you have a well-constructed `ListVectorPlot` to start with, because the format of `data` does not immediately correspond to a reasonable input for that function. I know that it plots *something*, but I am not sure that it is your intended output anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
data = Table[{{x, y}, {x, -y}}, {x, -6, 0}, {y, -6, 0}] ;
data1 = Table[{{x, y}, {x, -y}}, {x, 1, 6}, {y, 1, 6}]
Show[{ListVectorPlot[  data ], ListVectorPlot[  data1 ]},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

**addendum**

in one step

```
ListVectorPlot[{ data , data1 }, VectorPoints -> All]
```

[image]